# Open url tel scheme not working for some phone numbers

Tags: ios, swift, url, tel

I am using the below code to dial a phone number that I get from contacts:

```
func dialNumber(number : String) {

    let formatedNumber = number.components(separatedBy: NSCharacterSet.decimalDigits.inverted).joined(separator: "")
    print("formatedNumber:", formatedNumber)

    if let url = URL(string: "tel://\(formatedNumber)"),
        UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url) {
        if #available(iOS 10, *) {
            UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler:nil)
        } else {
            UIApplication.shared.openURL(url)
        }
    }
}
```

Additional info:

```
var urlTest = URL(string: "tel:+12345678900")!
print("UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url):", UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(urlTest)) // Returns true
UIApplication.shared.open(urlTest, options: [:], completionHandler:nil)

var urlTest = URL(string: "tel:2345678900")!
print("UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url):", UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(urlTest)) // Returns true
UIApplication.shared.open(urlTest, options: [:], completionHandler:nil)
```

The code works for numbers with Area code +1XXXYYYZZZZ and the phone number is dialed.

But it doesn't work for numbers like XXXYYYZZZZ.

If I open the contact using Address Book, the number XXXYYYZZZZ is recognized as a phone number. On clicking, the number gets dialed.

How can I get a similar behaviour as Address Book inside my app?

I do not want to add a region code +1 as the app will be used in other countries as well.

There are external libraries for identifying phone numbers but I'm trying to explore if there is a native solution.

If a number is not recognized, I even tried to open the contact in the address book so the user can dial the number from the contacts app, but it looks like address book is not a supported scheme.

Comment: Remove the //. Just have `tel:XXXYYYY`

Comment: thanks @Paulw11. I tried. unfortunately that doesn't solve the problem. Still doesn't work for XXXYYYZZZZ

Comment: Can you clarify "doesn't work" - Does `canOpenURL` return `false`? Do you get `false` if you pass a completion handler to `open`? Do you get any messages in the console?

Comment: I tested and pretty much any sequence of digits results in a prompt from the app to call the specified number or cancel

Comment: Sorry for not being clear earlier. I added additional code snippets. I am a beginner in Swift so i am finding it difficult to figure out :( . canOpenURL is returning true for both the scenarios. But my if condition is failing.  if let url = URL(string: "tel:\(number)"),UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url)

Comment: I should have use formattedNumber. Silly mistake. @Paulw11 solution works. I will update my question and accept your answer. Many thanks..